# PHP $$variables

Tags: php, variables

I want a statement something like:

```
IF(someVar == someOtherVar) {
//do some calculations here
}
```

It looks like this without using variables:

```
IF($_RESULT[priArrest]== 'No' ) {
//do some calculations here
}
```

I want to "build" that IF statement as `$x` using data from a CSV file named "matrixData"

```
$x='$_RESULT[';
$x.=$matrixData[0];
$x.="]='";
$x.=$matrixData[4];
$x.="'";
//$x defined as ....... $_RESULT[priArrest]== 'No'

IF($x) { 
//do some calculations here
echo ('BINGO');
}
```

`$x` defined as ....... `$_RESULT[priArrest]== 'No'`
`IF($x)` always returns `TRUE` because `$x` is defined (I understand why I'm getting `T` all the time).

I want `IF($x)` to return `T` only if the CONTENT of `$x` is true.
ie: `IF($x)` always evaluates whether `$x` is `TRUE`, not whether `$_RESULT[priArrest]=='No'`

What is the syntax to return the result of `$x` rather than the literal `$x`?
I can easily ECHO what I want (`$x`), but would like to learn how to embed the `$x` into an IF()
I've tried defining `$x` as `$$x`

Tried using (just to demonstrate my ignorance):

```
IF ($x) {
}


IF (($x)) {
}


IF (($$x)) {
}


IF ((${$x})) {
}


IF ((&$x)) {
}
```

Based on results of searching various sources of PHP help.

Comment: Erm... `$_RESULT[$matrixData[0]] = $matrixData[4];`? Or `==` for comparisons?

Comment: You're doing a bit more than a variable variable there. You've got an actual PHP expression. Maybe look in to [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

Comment: $x is ultimately always equal to a string value, which is why it's 'truthy'.  You want to test `if($_RESULT[$matrixData[0]] == $matrixData[4])`, which you can do in a single line without crafting a string first.

Comment: @mirabelle can you please post your comment as an answer?

Comment: erm Niet the Dark- it IS ==. The = you are referring to is setting $x.  However, the == in the compare statement is located within one of hte other variables.  Note the // line - $x defined as - you will see the ==

Comment: Thank you MIrabelle.  As an exercise, what is the syntax for using one variable???  Thx

Comment: *what is the syntax for using one variable* What do you mean by *using one variable*?

Comment: @A.L. - I meant instead of:  IF($matrixData[1] == $matrixData[2]) {.  }   I would like assign the query to $x and use IF($x) {   }.  Reason being the comparator is not always ==, it can be empty, !empty, >, <. My thought was to 'build' the query as $x and then use IF($x).  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As [rmirabelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680583/rmirabelle) wrote in a comment, you can use the condition directly:

```
if ($_RESULT[$matrixData[0]] == $matrixData[4]) {
    echo ('BINGO');
}
// Or use another condition:
if ($_RESULT[$matrixData[0]] < $matrixData[4]) {
    echo ('BINGO');
}
```

You can also store this boolean value for later use:

```
$x = ($_RESULT[$matrixData[0]] < $matrixData[4]);
// …
if ($x) {
    echo ('BINGO');
}
```